# How can I do background parsing of data with Symfony2?

Tags: php, parsing, symfony, background

I write a web application in PHP with Symfony2. The user can upload a CSV file with data that is saved to the database. The parsing of each row of the CSV file last about 0.2 seconds because I make some requests to the Google Maps API.

So when you upload a CSV file with 5000 rows, which is a realistic case in my app, it may take 16 minutes to parse the whole file.

I don't want that the user must wait 16 minutes until he can continue using my app. So my question is: how can I parse the CSV file in the background, so that the user can continue surfing?

Comment: Symfony2 has no background process / worker capability out of the box, so you have to roll your own.

Comment: I'd go with Gearman - easy to set up and works with PHP very well indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the upload insert a job into a job queue table, and have a [Command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) regularly run by [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that handles any work in the job queue table.

As processing proceeds on a job you can update the job table so a user can check back and see progress happening (eg you could have an ajax progress bar) & can tell when the job is complete.

This way you also de-couple the upload from the processing, and you can control how many jobs are processed at once.  Having long-running jobs launch directly from user input without a throttling / queuing system in place is a great way to open yourself up to a denial of service attack...

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I will try it this way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `kernel.terminate` event listener and do your parsing there. This event fires after response is sent to the browser. Sample implementation would be,

Service declaration,

```
//services.yml
csv_parse_listener:
    class: FQCN\Of\CsvParseListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onKernelTerminate }
```

Listener class,

```
namespace Your\namespace;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent;

class CsvParseListener
{
    public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if($request->get('_route') !== "Your_route"){
            return;
        }

        $csvFile = $request->files->get('file_field_name');

        //move file using $csvFile->move()
        //read and parse
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the event "kernel.terminate" callable in Symfony2? My web application throws a error when I want to use it.

Comment: Why would call it directely? If it is registered then `onKernelTerminate` method will automatically be called. What is the error message?

Comment: The error was made by me ;)
But now the `onKernelTerminate` method isn't called, my application do not run the code in this method.
I looked in the file `vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvent` but there was no 'terminate' event.

Comment: Odd, it should be in the end of the class, `const TERMINATE = 'kernel.terminate';`. What is your Symfony version?

Comment: My Symfony version is 2.0.15, the newest one.

Comment: I see it is [there](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.php#L104). Can you go to profiler page in dev mode and then select events tab on the left? There you will see the list of listeners fired.

Comment: The events tab don't show the terminate event. I have the Symfony Standard Edition 2.0.15 from here: http://symfony.com/download.
Which one do you use. The same or something from Github?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12123/discussion-between-m2mdas-and-rotespferd)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script that's just for processing the CSV file, and exec() that script from the script that manages the upload. On *IX systems you can make the command started by exec() run in the background by appending an & character.

You'll probably also want to include a script that will let the user check the progress of the processing.

Comment: exec'ing a long running job from a web request sounds risky to me.